# How to hide the border between 2 cells while keeping them separate?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I hide the border between those two cells while keeping them separate in the HTML code (i.e. *not* merging the cells using a `colspan="2"`)? The sense of using *two* separate cells instead of *one* merged cell is to have the `user-select: none` attribute only for the first cell.

The default look of the borders (see image) should be kept as far as possible.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="user-select: none">1)</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The expected result:
[image]

**I use Chrome.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following settings:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: double;
}

tr:first-child>td:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}

tr:first-child>td:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="user-select: none">1)</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Version 2: Default borders - only possible with interruptions on the inner borders:

```css
tr:first-child>td:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}

tr:first-child>td:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="user-select: none">1)</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Version 3: nested table in merged cell:

```css
table table {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="user-select: none">1)</td>
          <td>Javascript</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But you use another border design. I want to keep original.

Comment: By default, there are inner and outer borders (table and cell). If you remove the left/rigth part of the cell borders alone, there will be a small interruption in the inner borders, so what you want is actually not possible. (Try to delete the whole CSS rule for `table` in my snippet, then you see what I mean)

Comment: >"actually not possible" - as always(

Comment: But my result isn't really that different (?)

Comment: I can create workarounds by myself too. But the sense was to do this with original `html` border (without another `css` border styles). Strange that it is so big problem.

Comment: Let be even with small interruptions. Interesting to see.

Comment: every solution will be a workaround in this case. Another one would be to merge these two cells and use a nested table inside it.

Comment: 1) So can you do this with interruptions? 2) How to merge in 1 cell but with working `user-select: none` for "1)"?

Comment: I just added a second snippet to my answer

Comment: Cool +1. At least the graphical design is what I need. But for big table, it would be like doubling the code size. What about the variant with interruptions?

Comment: Okay, I added that too

Comment: Thanks. What about making this border white or transparent?

Comment: ?? - back to answer #1 ;-) You wanted the default look...

Comment: I mean to use color `#FFFFFF` to hide this border (between the cells), without applying `color` to other sides. The right border works, but the left becomes grey instead of white - very strange. Or some style to make it transparent (likely not possible).

Comment: Do you know why it is grey? Or it is white on your end?

Comment: I suppose that's due to the border default style for tables, which in most browsers is "outset" and creates some kind of shadow effect.

Comment: But if no border - should be no shadow. Looks like a bug.

Comment: I would use my own solution - `<span style="user-select: none">` instead of `<td>`, but your 3 versions are useful.

Comment: See my new question about borders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214138

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the `table` border style.
Replace `red` and `blue` color as you want.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

table:before {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
}

td {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style="user-select: none">1)</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please make a snippet.

Comment: you want keep second td border?

Comment: But it has another border design. For example, the original has different color intensity (not only black).

Comment: you can customize the table border style,updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for creative +1. But the main wish it to keep the original borders. Maybe with interruptions...

Comment: what do you mean, original border?

Comment: The graphical effect of `border=1`. So without using another `css` border styles. Just to let 1 border (between cells) be `none` or totally white or transparent.

Comment: if you don't mind, you can change the pixel values for both table and table:before to looks same with the original one.

Comment: It is interesting if possible to copy the design. You can add one more snippet.

Comment: let me know the outer and inner border color, and the space between them.

Comment: To copy the expected result of the question. It reminds a gradient effect.

Comment: You can see this default design zoomed to understand its model: https://i.imgur.com/NIP0v32.png

Comment: Why doesn't the text cursor appear (to select text) over "Javascript" in your snippet?

Answer (score 1):

```css
td {
  border: none;
}
table {
  border: double;
}
```

```html
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td style="user-select: none">1)</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also you can do is simply just give border=0 without giving style attribute
Check this snippet.

Comment: @oleedd pls check now

Comment: But it has another border design. I need to keep the original design. For example, the original has different color intensity (not only black).