# How to keep the border double between cells?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
#tb2 td { display:block }
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tb1">
  <td>1) text</td>
  <td>2) text</td>
  <td>3) text</td>
</table>

<hr/>

<table border="1" id="tb2">
  <td>1) text</td>
  <td>2) text</td>
  <td>3) text</td>
</table>
```

The border is double between cells:
[image]

If I add `td {display: block}` to make a column, the border between cells isn't double:
[image]

Why and how to keep it double?

**Things to consider:**
**1) No using additional html elements.

2) No using css borders.**

**I use Chrome.**

This question is a bit theoretical. That is why no `<tr>`, `<tbody>` etc.

Comment: Your table is not valid HTML

Comment: What is your usecase? An exercise in writing invalid HTML?

Comment: @mplungjan To understand why it works in row but not in column.

Comment: What is there to understand when the html is invalid. If the basis is not correct, you will have a hard time correcting it

Comment: @mplungjan It is theoretical. Totally invalid will give an error - it isn't our case.

Comment: Just because the browser bends over backwards to try to render our data, does not mean we should tak invalid HTML and try to tweak it to work the way we want, when there is a perfectly good solution: Use valid markup. There is no point in you using table cells when you can use spans with inline block and widths or divs in flex instead

Comment: @mplungjan I use `<table>` because of `border=1` (common for `<td>`).

Comment: The inline border attribute is deprecated and is a sideeffect you are abusing to produce invalid HTML for arbitrary reasons.

Comment: Deprecated but it has reverse symmetrical grey and black colors. It requires much coding to repeat this with only css.

Comment: It is still invalid HTML with deprecated inline attributes. Not a great idea

Comment: Okay, tell it to us straight - is it a situation of actually _can’t_ change the markup, or just one of “don’t want to, because complicated” … If it is the latter, then there is really not much to discuss here.

Comment: @CBroe I want to get something new for me. That is why I said about theoretical motivation. I knew changing html and css border ways before asking. I got 1 new method from the answers. Maybe something more exists?..

Comment: BTW  if no tr and no tbody in the code, the browsers generate them anyway ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus It doesn't generate them if to create a table using JavaScript (what I actually do). Proof: https://i.imgur.com/GGMU8OW.png

Comment: well : https://jsfiddle.net/adrgh08o/ not there but you style them ;)

Comment: alos with the inspector, you find them : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzHXX.jpg ;)  there is actually magic going on after all

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I don't understand many color circles on right because there is not English but I like `border = 1` (not css) because black line always stay near grey line there (reverse symmetry).

Answer (score 1):

> If I add `td {display: block}` to make a column, the border between cells isn't double

That's not how columns/rows in tables work. Use the `<tr>` element to create a table row. Within that row, you can then use `<td>` to create columns. No CSS modifications of the `display` property are needed.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1) text</td>
    <td>2) text</td>
    <td>3) text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4) text</td>
    <td>5) text</td>
    <td>6) text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

> No using additional html elements.

If you really want to roll the dice and hope that your browser is able to correct the malformed html table without rows, you can use `margin`:

```css
td {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
td:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <td>4) text</td>
  <td>5) text</td>
  <td>6) text</td>
</table>
```

Comment: No using additional html elements.

Comment: And I need only 1 column, not 3

Comment: I updated the answer. Keep in mind that what you are trying to do is invalid html. It should not be used in production.

Comment: ＋1 Good, but I wanted with some `display` value or something like that. Possible?

Comment: CSS doesn't invalid HTML. It cannot (javascript would if you did modify the DOM turning td into real div ) , it' only about styling, so if td are turned into blocks at screen, they can also get a margin. default display is table-cell, but you can reset it and that's what CSS is about. Do your own styling ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus The thing that's invalid is the HTML table without table rows, not the CSS :)

Comment: oups, my bad ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the reason for the question.

Don't use side effects of random elements because you want to use deprecated inline BORDER attribute

There is not particular need to know why something does not work when it is not valid markup. To fix it, use valid markup

See my second example. It looks the way it should because it is valid markup

The third is also valid but is using divs

Without border or extra HTML, you can try this:

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  padding 2px;
  margin 2px;
}

#tb2 td {
  display: block;
}

div.border {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}

div.container {
  width: 60px
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tb1">
  <td>1) text</td>
  <td>2) text</td>
  <td>3) text</td>
</table>

<hr/>

<table border="1" id="tb2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1) text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2) text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3) text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

<div class="border container">
  <div class="border">1) text</div>
  <div class="border">2) text</div>
  <div class="border">3) text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that it will work with `<tr>` and `<tbody>` but I want without them because it works in row.

Comment: I wanted with some `display` value or something like that. Possible?

Comment: So I have two working versions using valid markup

Comment: Things to consider:
1) No using additional html elements.
**2) No using css borders.**

Comment: I want to get something new: I know additional html elements and css borders ways without you.

Comment: Things to consider: Don't use side effects of random elements because you want to use deprecated inline BORDER attribute

Comment: Deprecated but it has reverse symmetrical grey and black colors.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong turning your tds into block but your are loosing the table-layout model (it includes `border-spacing`). You are missing that gap in between your block td , margin works fine with block, add it.

```css
#tb2 td {
  display: block
}

#tb2 td+td {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tb1">
  <tr>
    <td>1) text</td>
    <td>2) text</td>
    <td>3) text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr/>

<table border="1" id="tb2">
  <tr>
    <td>1) text</td>
    <td>2) text</td>
    <td>3) text</td>
  </tr>
```

if you reset `border-spacing` and want to update that margin, you can use a custon CSS `var()` to only reset it once for all .

```css
table {
  --borderSpacing: 5px;/* reset here the value */
  border-spacing: var(--borderSpacing);/*   use the var() value */
}

#tb2 td {
  display: block
}

#tb2 td+td {
  margin-top: var(--borderSpacing);/*   use the var() value */
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tb1">
  <tr>
    <td>1) text</td>
    <td>2) text</td>
    <td>3) text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr/>

<table border="1" id="tb2">
  <tr>
    <td>1) text</td>
    <td>2) text</td>
    <td>3) text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you do not like the display:block alternative, then flex or grid on the parent will do too

```css
table {
  --borderSpacing: 5px;
  /* reset here the value */
  border-spacing: var(--borderSpacing);
  /*   use the var() value */
}

#tb2 tr {
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--borderSpacing);
  /*   use the var() value */
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tb1">
  <tr>
    <td>1) text</td>
    <td>2) text</td>
    <td>3) text</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr/>

<table border="1" id="tb2">
  <tr>
    <td>1) text</td>
    <td>2) text</td>
    <td>3) text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OK, but I already got this way from a previous answer (your selector is much shorter). I want something with `display` value.

Comment: @oleedd you seems to reject automatically all the solutions, why? can you explain exactly what you want? there is no magic value of display that will do the job here, you need more CSS, as simple as that.

Comment: I don't reject all. This one is suitable. I just reject what I knew before (in the "Things to consider") to get only new. I just want more ;)

Comment: @oleedd  if you want table element to pile , turns them into blocks. any block level display value will do. Added a snippet with a grid option

Comment: I mean some `display` or something similar to make borders double (separated) automatically (like in a row) - without `px` spacing => so some another method.

Comment: @oleedd You have to understand that if you reset display:table-cell to anything else, then border-spacing is not there anymore, you killed it, and margin is to use iinstead  default border-spacing is average 2-3px anyway, but you can reset it with any other unit value. Your wasting your time hopping that border-spacing can be appplied elsewhere than a table-layout. default border-spacing is not 0 but defaut margin can be and gap/grid-gap are 0. A reset is to be done anyway. use a custom CSS var() to make that easy . We can't help you more than we did at that point. Compromise >your keyword  ;)

Comment: OK, if it resets then maybe something else (not `display`). I tried `max-width` to force it go to the next row, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @oleedd you have not tried float and clear .. that kills display too ... i'm giving up !

Answer (score 0):

A solution with only `display` BUT you need to change the HTML. Either you change the HTML or you add more CSS otherwise we can't do what you want with nothing.

```css
#tb1 tr { display:contents }
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tb1">
  <tr><td>1) text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2) text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3) text</td></tr>
</table>

<hr/>

<table border="1" id="tb2">
  <tr><td>1) text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2) text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3) text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The thing is I know the way with changing html. This site is to get something new.

Comment: @oleedd this site is to answer *clear* questions, it's not for you to get something new. You may know how to change the HTML but someone else facing the same issue may not hence my answer (and other answers). This question it not for *you*, it's for the community and it is a standalone question (what you know or don't know is irrelevant to what the question contain)

Comment: You are a bit wrong. People request information what they need on SE sites. But this site is more about practical solutions than theory.

Comment: @oleedd people request information : yes but what people know or not is irrelevant. Your level of knowledge is irrelevant to the question asked. We don't answer question based on what you know, we do it based on what the question contain. You are using an invalid code, your listed unclear requirements, etc. We are obliged to give accurate answers using valid code and common methods because people that will see the question need to know that what you are using is invalid and need to find the valid method (even if you will not accept them)

Comment: People can ask - what except this and this. I just said more strictly. Invalid is with errors, this one is non-standard - it may work (invalid can't work).

Comment: "or you add more css" - it is suitable. But not css borders because I like the `border=1` attribute design.